# basic_ostream::operator<< char ambiguity between basic_ostream and custom class

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using MyStream = std::stringstream;

struct MyTime
{
    explicit MyTime(std::time_t time) // w/o explicit the MyTime operator << is ambigous as well
    {
    }
};

/*

having this overload of course solves everything, but that seems wrong

std::stringstream &operator<<(std::stringstream &stream, char c)
{
    stream.put(c);
    return stream;
}
*/

MyStream& operator<<(MyStream &stream, std::time_t time)
{
    return stream;
}

MyStream& operator<<(MyStream &stream, const MyTime &time)
{
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyStream stream;
    stream << 'Z';
    return 0;
}
```

Without having the `std::stringstream &operator<<(std::stringstream &stream, char c)` declaration, the `stream << 'Z'` fails with abmiguity (since there is no overload for `char`, it can be promoted to both short and hit `basic_ostream` and to `time_t` and hit `MyStream`). I don't really want to use `basic_ostream::put`) since the chaining of multiple writes would then look ugly (of course if that is the last resort then...). So this gives me two questions:

1. What is the rationale of not having a `char` overload for `basic_ostream::operator<<` ? Is that all down to character encodings?
2. Are there any nice solutions (something that I am missing apart from using `put` or having the `char` overload)?

**UPDATE**

So it seems that inheriting from `std::stringstream` vs using `using` fixes the issue, but this leaves me with the dilemma of going against the "never inherit from stl classes" dogma.

I guess the issue arises from the fact that `using` does not actually introduce a new type, thus the ambiguity:

> A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name.

Comment: There are choice between your `operator<<(std::stringstream& stream, std::time_t time)` and `template <..>operator<<(basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&, CharT)`. None is better.

Comment: There is an implementation for `char`, but [it's a free function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) rather than a member. My guess is that it doesn't get chosen because it's implemented on `basic_ostream` rather than the more specific `stringstream` -- something you could do for your custom type as well.

Comment: You might fix issue by implementing overload with `std::ostream` instead of `std::stringstream` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8GYE6rs8v).

Comment: @Thomas ahh, thanks, I missed the free function. Ok this gives more insight.

Comment: @Jarod42 I considered that, I kind of wanted the ease of taking out the string afterwards, but yeah I may simply wrap my own buffer and live with `std::ostream`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, will actually try to understand the resolution rules that rule out the free function in this case, many thanks, this was something that I totally missed.

Comment: @Thomas actually inheriting from `std::stringstream`  vs using `using` fixes this. Still not sure about the resolution rules.

Answer (score 1):

You might fix issue by implementing overload with `std::ostream` instead of `std::stringstream`

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, std::time_t )
{
    return stream;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const MyTime &)
{
    return stream;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8GYE6rs8v).

Comment: This solve the issue, although this kind of takes away my intention to have a specific behaviour for my exact stream type, but I guess there are no better ways around this.

Comment: just concluded that actually deriving (which is something that everyone warns against for std classes) fixes the issue. So sorry , I'll have to de-accept this since that retains the semantics I need. But I am not sure how the resolution rules affect this.